# Product over the primes with relation to the Dirichlet series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers, products, dirichlet-series

What is the value of $\displaystyle \prod_p\left(1+\frac{p^s}{(p^s-1)^2}\right)$
I got this product by defining a function $a(n)$ such that $a(n)=a(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}...p_n^{a_n})=a_1a_2a_3...a_n$ and using that function in a Dirichelt series 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s}=\prod_p(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(p^n)}{p^{ns}})=\prod_p(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{p^{ns}})=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{p^s}{(p^s-1)^2}\right)$
I defined $a(1)=1$

Comment: How does someone get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Dirichlet generating function (g.f.) of
[OEIS sequence A005361](https://oeis.org/A005361) "Product of exponents of prime factorization of n" which states "Dirichlet g.f.: ζ(s)ζ(2s)ζ(3s)/ζ(6s)".
The proof is simple. Recall that the definition of
the Riemann zeta function is
$$ \zeta(s) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} =
\prod_p (1-p^{-s})^{-1}.$$ This implies that
$$ \zeta(ks) = \prod_p (1-X^k)^{-1} $$ where
$\, X := p^{-s}.\,$ Now our Dirichlet g.f. is
($X\,$ or $\,X^{-1}\,$ the same here)

$$ G(s) := \prod_p
\left(1 + \frac{p^s}{(p^s-1)^2} \right)
= \prod_p \left(1 + \frac{X}{(1-X)^2}\right).$$

Use some algebra to get
$$ 1 + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1-x+x^2}{(1-x)^2}
= \frac{1-x^6}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}.$$
Combine previous equations to get
$$ G(s) = ζ(s)ζ(2s)ζ(3s)/ζ(6s). $$